# VBA Code to change word footer in multiple files based on page number

Tags: vba, ms-word, footer

I have a macro that runs to make a single page doc into a 5 page doc (NCR Duplicates) for all files in a folder.

I am using a set of nested `IF` fields in my footer, which changes the footer based on page number. The field looks like this

```
Text here {If{PAGE}="1""Original"{If{PAGE}="2""Copy 1"
{If{PAGE}="3""Copy 2"{If{PAGE}="4""Copy 3"{If{PAGE}="5""Copy 4"}}}}} 
Other Text
```

I am trying to figure out how to add this footer to all the documents in a folder. It doesn't need to use field, if there is a way simply based on page number.

I have bashed my head against the wall, searched like crazy, and now come hat in hand.

The macro to make the duplicate copies is:

```
Sub Make5CopiesNCR()

  vDirectory = BrowseForFolder

 vFile = Dir(vDirectory & "\" & "*.*")

Do While vFile <> ""

Documents.Open FileName:=vDirectory & "\" & vFile

MakeCopies

vFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub

End Sub

Private Sub MakeCopies()
Dim i As Integer
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Copy
For i = 1 To 6
Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
Next
With ActiveDocument
.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Name:=6 'Page number
.Bookmarks("\Page").Select
With Selection
  .Delete
ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges, OriginalFormat:=wdWordDocument
  End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you make each page a section and unlink headers and footers between first and second sections then you can simplify your footers to Original on the first page.  Restart numbering in the second section and then just have Copy {pagenumber} as the footer.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below the question to include the code being used to combine the documents. It's not quite clear what you want, since if the footer is in the first document and the rest are inserted they *should* be inheriting the first page's footer automatically. If this isn't happening, we need to understand exactly what you're doing...

Comment: My apologies if I wasn't clear. I run a mail-merge to create individual word doc files. Then I run the code above to create 4 additional pages in each file. My final step would be to then take each 5 page doc and have the footers read for page one "Original", then "Copy 1", "Copy 2", and so on. What I have been doing is opening each doc and pasting the nested if statement to create the footers I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with using a mailmerge with your field construction is that it gets converted to the result. Try a field coded as:

{={PAGE}-1 \# "'Copy {={PAGE}-1}';;'Original'"}

Now, if you create the required 5 pages in your mailmerge main document, all the outputs will likewise be in multiples of 5 pages, with the correct page numbering.

Even if you use a mailmerge main document with only a single page, the outputs will have the field coding required to produce the correct numbering for however many more pages you want to add to the outputs.

As for replicating this in your existing files, simply create a document with the required footer content, then use a macro like:

```
Sub ReplicateFooter()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim DocSrc As Document, DocTgt As Document, Rng As Range
Dim StrPth As String, StrNm As String, StrSrc As String
Set DocSrc = ActiveDocument
Set Rng = DocSrc.Sections.First.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
StrPth = DocSrc.Path & "\": StrSrc = DocSrc.FullName
StrNm = Dir(StrPth & "*.doc", vbNormal)
While StrNm <> ""
  If StrPth & StrNm <> StrSrc Then
    Set DocTgt = Documents.Open(FileName:=StrPth & StrNm, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    With DocTgt
      With .Sections.First.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        .FormattedText = Rng.FormattedText
        .Characters.Last.Text = vbNullString
      End With
      .Close True
    End With
  End If
  StrNm = Dir()
Wend
Set Rng = Nothing: Set DocTgt = Nothing: Set DocSrc = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```